# “It’s him or us!” What does it mean?

Tags: meaning

I've across the phrase below:

> “It’s him or us!”

Could you please tell me what it exactly means?

The fuller text:

> “We should kill him,” Henry says into the dark without warning,
>   “before he kills us.” David feels the small hairs on the back of his
>   neck stirring. It’s as if everyone has stopped breathing. He takes a
>   deep breath and says, his voice outraged beneath the evenness, “Don’t
>   be ridiculous, Henry—we don’t know that Ian killed anybody.” Henry
>   says recklessly, “**It’s him or us!**”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s a summary of Henry’s first statement, i.e. we must kill him, or we will be killed. It’s him [to be killed], or us [to be killed].

Comment: Yes, and also common like this:It's us or them.